# Meaning/logic of "bend the curve"?

Tags: expressions

I think the meaning of this is to adjust a situation to your desired outcome, but I fail to see how this expression came to be. A **curve is already bent**, so I fail to understand how come this expression came to have such a meaning.

Comment: Just because something is already curved doesn't mean that you can't bend it some more.

Comment: Never heard of it as a phrase. And so without context it's unanswerable. Do you have any examples to show the context it's used in?

Comment: @AndyT : http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/bending-the-curve.html

Comment: Survey results include common variations. Distorting that curve to suit your agenda is a cheap way to strengthen your argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is normally applied to data that already shows some trend, specifically to a curve fit through the data (even if that best-fit-curve is a straight line).

The process of changing the parameters so that the resulting curve is more to your liking is therefore referred to as bending the curve.